# Compilation error: Expected end of statement because of an Xpath

Tags: xpath, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to understand what is wrong but I can't. I have used XPath so many times in my code, but this time I keep getting the error

> Expected end of statement

without an obvious reason.

The error seems to be occurred because of the simple XPath:

```
xpathId = ".//h2[contains(.,'"&Identifier&"')]"
```

`Identifier` is a variable that is set when the function is called:

```
Function Test(Identifier)
```

Comment: What is the value of `Identifier` when the error occurs?

Comment: As above.  If `Identifier` contains a single quote (for example) then it will mess up your closing quote and generate this error.

Comment: Did you check/count your end ifs and other block terminators?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

xpathId := ".//h2[contains(.,'"&Identifier&"')]"